# set overflow hidden in some cases

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, visibility

How can I set overflow hidden in cases where the html go's outside the screen

Right now I have set html `{overflow: hidden;}` in the `head` tag off the page.
So, it's hidden all the time

In my particular case the errors that I show in the registration process cannot be seen on my 13inch laptop, but I don't want to show the scrollbars all the time.

That's why I want it to set(or unset) based on the fact if there is overflow or not.

What would be the best way?

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
<div id="overflowHidden" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="contentContainer">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Set a height on `#overflowHidden` and, when the content changes in `#contentContainer`, check the height compared to that of `#overflowHidden` and set the overflow attribute on `#overflowHidden` as appropriate.

Not the most elegant solution, but it would be fairly easy to turn on and off (for testing v. production).

Comment: but,I have to take another variable into account here.
The fact that I want nothing done (keep hidden), if it fits the screensize.

Answer (score 0):

Will 'overflow:auto' not suffice?

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html

> auto:The behavior of the 'auto' value
>   is user agent-dependent, but should
>   cause a scrolling mechanism to be
>   provided for overflowing boxes

Comment: yes, but I used divs with the left property set to something like minus 700. It will cause the scrollbars always to be shown and that's a problem, - also in my layout maybe, but that's something else.

Comment: hmm, maybe rethink your layout strategy? Maybe you are trying to solve a problem which wouldn't exist if your page structure was different. Just a thought.  Good luck!

Comment: yes, I know that, but that will cause more headache then this problem, because I know have it the way I want it.
If I can't find find a workaraound, I might do that, or I will move the errorbox upword.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you only set the scrollbar for vertical scrolling?

You could do this using overflow-y: auto; and overflow-x: hidden;

This will show a vertical scrollbar (only when you need it), but will not show a horizontal scrollbar. This way the hidden divs with negative property won't show, even if you decide to show the scrollbars.

Comment: thanks, that helps. Mayby, I can also do something with document.height() or window.height(), if neccasary. Do you set those with jquery like $('body').css("overflow-y", "auto")??

Comment: You could set it with jquery, but I was thinking more in the lines of simple css in the head part of the page. Just like where you have html {overflow: hidden;}, you could put body {overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;}.

Comment: I need to do it with jquery, because the top off the page is a template. It worked. Maybe I can detail it more using document.height()